# How to match text with umlauts?

Tags: regex

I try to match the text "Rasensamen und Dünger" in the following string:

```
/rasensamen.html">Rasensamen und Dünger</a>
```

I tried it like this:

```
>[\w+ ]+<\/a>
```

https://regex101.com/r/FolwpQ/1

But it does not match, even though it should. But if I remove the `ü` from `Dünger` then it works?

Comment: `\w` doesn't match UTF8 characters by default, it only matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: Add the `u` flag : https://regex101.com/r/FolwpQ/3 (or as a better alternative, don't use regex to parse HTML but rather an HTML parser)

Comment: So I guess I have to use `>([\w+ äöü]+)<\/a>`

Comment: Use a DOM parser, or a workaround like `>[^<]+<\/a>` for those HTMLs that you are in control of if you have any "special" requirements.

Comment: `\w+` imside `[...]` doesn't make any sense

Comment: Yeah, that too. You probably meant `[A-Za-z0-9 ]+`. The `+` is removed because you probably don't want to match it, the `\w` is changed into `A-Za-z0-9` because you might not want to match `_` either which `\w` matches in addition to alphanumeric chars.

Comment: @anubhava, if `\w+` imside `[...]` does not make any sense, then why does it work as expected now with `>([\w+ äöü]+)<\/a>` ?

Comment: @Black `[\w+]+` matches one or more word and `+` chars. Inside `[...]`, `+` is a plus symbol, not a quantifier. Also, have a look at [`>[\p{L} ]+<\/a>`](https://regex101.com/r/FolwpQ/4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many regex engines provide a unicode option that when turned on, matches with full unicode support. In the pcre flavor, this makes `\w` match `[\p{L}\p{N}_]`, which includes latin letters with umlauts.

In regex101.com, just add the `u` option by clicking on the options shown on the left of the flag.

You can simplify your regex to this:

```
>[\w+ ]+<\/a>
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FolwpQ/5)

Note that the regex you suggested in the comments, `>([\w+ äöü]+)<\/a>` doesn't work if there is a sharp s.